# Meta Data Search Functionality for Rackspace Cloud Files Container?

Tags: php, file, search, architecture, cloud

This is an Architectural question concerning the Rackspace Cloud Files. I've successfully added Cloud Files functionality (PHP/MySQL - Classes/Package) to one of my projects (domains) and would like to somehow provide search functionality for these files (PDF's, etc) to other projects (domains/subdomains). It doesn't seem like the Meta Data within the Cloud Files can be searched directly, without requesting all object information within the Container (not very efficient).

The PHP Cloud Files package does provide a way to search by file "prefix", but not thru a Meta Search. This prefix is what is typically used to create seudo-directories in your container.

I'd like to search thru the Meta Data provided in the Cloud Files (efficiently). I may end up having several domains sharing a Cloud Files Container of files with Meta Data for each file. Should I create an external MySQL database accessible from all the domains to manage the meta data search functionality for the Containers? Is there anything already created for this type of purpose?

Example Situation: A PDF is created at domain 1. PDF is written to the Cloud Files container. Meta Data includes a person's related information (Cloud Files Meta - Not PDF Meta). Domain 2 needs to search the shared Cloud Files Container by a person's identity and present all related files for that person.

Thanks for any comments/help. Jeff Walters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through the API as well and did not see any method to search the metadata. I would go with the MySQL solution for this project and store any the metadata you need in database.

I don't think there is already a solution built for this purpose, but it should be rather easy to build. I do use S3 in several of my projects and track the objects with additional metadata in MySQL tables.